# Proof of Matrices existence.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I'm trying to solve this

> Let $A\in M_{m,n}(K)$. Prove that exists invertible matrices $B\in M_m(K)$ and $C\in M_n(K)$ such that $(BAC)_{i,j}=d_{i,j}$, where $d_{1,1}=d_{2,2}=\cdots=d_{t,t}=0$ and $d_{i,j}\neq0$.

- $M_{m,n}(K)$ Stands for the Vector Space of Matrices $m$ by $n$ over a field $K$.
- $M_{n}(K)$ Stands for Square matrices of order $n$ by $n$.

I've tried to get a clear view with an example from a $3\times2$ matrix, only to find it gets me no conditions for such matrices $B$ and $C$, let alone know if these are invertible.

I don't know how Should I tackle this problem. Any hint?

Comment: This doesn't seem possible if $A$ is a zero-matrix

Comment: The question has no meaning unless $m = n$, and even the statement is false (e.g., if $A$ is not invertible).

Instead of working with matrices, work with linear transformations. So, let $M$ be a vector space over $K$ of dimension $m$, and let $N$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space over the same field.  You have a linear transformation $A : M \rightarrow N$, and you are asking if there exist invertible linear transformations $C$ on $M$ and $B$ on $N$ such that
$BAC = I$, the identity transformation, but on what vector space?

Comment: @avs Why do you say "The question has no meaning unless m=n" ? The product of the matrices is well defined.

Comment: Notably, for matrices $D$ and $A$: there exist matrices $B$ and $C$ such that $BAC = D$ if and only if $A$ and $D$ have the same rank.  So, what we're really asking is "which values are possible for the rank of $D$ if $D$ fits the required pattern?"

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Why does the rank of A and D has to be the same?

Comment: @CésarRosendo because $B$ and $C$ are invertible.  $BA$ has the same nullspace as $A$, and $BAC$ has the same range (column space) as $BA$.

Comment: Are your sure that it isn't $d_{i,i} \ne 0$ for $1\le i \le t$ and $d_{i,j} = 0$ otherwise?